# SQLAlchemy - subquery in a WHERE clause

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, subquery

I've just recently started using SQLAlchemy and am still having trouble wrapping my head around some of the concepts.

Boiled down to the essential elements, I have two tables like this (this is through Flask-SQLAlchemy):

```
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

class Posts(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'posts'
    post_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.user_id'))
    post_time = db.Column(db.DateTime)

    user = db.relationship('User', backref='posts')
```

How would I go about querying for a list of users and their newest post (excluding users with no posts). If I was using SQL, I would do:

```
SELECT [whatever]
FROM posts AS p
    LEFT JOIN users AS u ON u.user_id = p.user_id
WHERE p.post_time = (SELECT MAX(post_time) FROM posts WHERE user_id = u.user_id)
```

So I know exactly the "desired" SQL to get the effect I want, but no idea how to express it "properly" in SQLAlchemy.

Edit: in case it's important, I'm on SQLAlchemy 0.6.6.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

This should work (different SQL, same result):

```
t = Session.query(
    Posts.user_id,
    func.max(Posts.post_time).label('max_post_time'),
).group_by(Posts.user_id).subquery('t')

query = Session.query(User, Posts).filter(and_(
    User.user_id == Posts.user_id,
    User.user_id == t.c.user_id,
    Posts.post_time == t.c.max_post_time,
))

for user, post in query:
    print user.user_id, post.post_id
```

> Where c stands for 'columns'

Answer (score 68):

the previous answer works, but also the exact sql you asked for is written much as the actual statement:

```
print s.query(User, Posts).\
    outerjoin(Posts.user).\
    filter(Posts.post_time==\
        s.query(
            func.max(Posts.post_time)
        ).
        filter(Posts.user_id==User.user_id).
        correlate(User).
        as_scalar()
    )
```

I guess the "concept" that isn't necessarily apparent is that as_scalar() is currently needed to establish a subquery as a "scalar" (it should probably assume that from the context against ==).

Edit:  Confirmed, that's buggy behavior, completed ticket #2190.  In the current tip or release 0.7.2, the as_scalar() is called automatically and the above query can be:

```
print s.query(User, Posts).\
    outerjoin(Posts.user).\
    filter(Posts.post_time==\
        s.query(
            func.max(Posts.post_time)
        ).
        filter(Posts.user_id==User.user_id).
        correlate(User)
    )
```

Answer (score 3):

It is usually expressed similarly to the actual SQL - you create a subquery that returns single result and compare against that - however what sometimes can be ***real pain*** is if you have to use a table in the subquery that you are already querying or joining on.

Solution is to create an **aliased** version of the model to reference in the subquery.

So let's say you are already operating in a connection where you have an existing `Posts` `model` and some basic `query` ready - now, you'd want to query for the list of latest (single) post from each user, you'd filter the query like:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import aliased
posts2 = aliased(Posts) # create aliased version

query = query.filter(
    model.post_id
    ==
    Posts.query # create query directly from model, NOT from the aliased version!
        .with_entities(posts2.post_id) # only select column "post_id"
        .filter(
            posts2.user_id == model.user_id
        )
        .order_by(posts2.post_id.desc()) # assume higher id == newer post
        .limit(1) # we must limit to a single row so we only get 1 value
)
```

I've purposedly did not use the `func.max` because I consider that a simpler version and it's already in other answers, this example I think will be useful to people that generally find this question because they are looking for a solution how to subquery the same table.

Comment: Thanks for posting a modern answer that more readily adapts to `select()` style queries in sqlalchemy 1.4/2.0 versions.