# Subquery in WHERE clause

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sqlalchemy, subquery

I am currently working on getting the following query run with sqlalchemy.

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    qsreport_test.JiraFehlerFreigabeReleaseTestData a 
WHERE a.dtime = (
    SELECT 
        max(dtime) 
    FROM 
        qsreport_test.JiraFehlerFreigabeReleaseTestData b 
    WHERE 
        b.key=a.key 
    AND 
        b.testplanname=a.testplanname 
    AND 
        b.priority=a.priority
) 
GROUP BY 
    a.testplanname, a.priority
```

I searched here and found 
[SQLAlchemy - subquery in a WHERE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6206600/sqlalchemy-subquery-in-a-where-clause) 
and I also know 
http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/tutorial.html#using-subqueries 
but I still do not get my query to work.

Here are two of my tries. The first one can be performed but does not give me the same result as the manual executed query. The second one can be performed and is now working (was missing a parenthesis before).

Try 1:

```
subq = session.query(JiraFehlerFreigabeReleaseTestData.key, JiraFehlerFreigabeReleaseTestData.testplanname, JiraFehlerFreigabeReleaseTestData.priority, func.max(JiraFehlerFreigabeReleaseTestData.dtime).label('max_dtime')).filter(JiraFehlerFreigabeReleaseTestData.key == key).filter(JiraFehlerFreigabeReleaseTestData.dtime <= dtime).subquery()
res = session.query(JiraFehlerFreigabeReleaseTestData).filter(and_(JiraFehlerFreigabeReleaseTestData.key == subq.c.key, JiraFehlerFreigabeReleaseTestData.testplanname == subq.c.testplanname, JiraFehlerFreigabeReleaseTestData.priority == subq.c.priority, JiraFehlerFreigabeReleaseTestData.dtime == subq.c.max_dtime)).group_by(JiraFehlerFreigabeReleaseTestData.testplanname).order_by(JiraFehlerFreigabeReleaseTestData.dtime.desc()).all()
```

Try 2:

```
b = aliased(JiraFehlerFreigabeReleaseTestData, name='b')
res = session.query(JiraFehlerFreigabeReleaseTestData).filter(JiraFehlerFreigabeReleaseTestData.dtime == (session.query(func.max(b.dtime)).filter(b.key == JiraFehlerFreigabeReleaseTestData.key).filter(b.testplanname == JiraFehlerFreigabeReleaseTestData.testplanname).filter(b.priority == JiraFehlerFreigabeReleaseTestData.priority))).group_by(JiraFehlerFreigabeReleaseTestData.testplanname,JiraFehlerFreigabeReleaseTestData.priority).order_by(JiraFehlerFreigabeReleaseTestData.dtime.desc()).all()
```

Please show me what I'm doing wrong. My problem is that I do not completely understand how to reference the table of the main query in the subquery. Especially as the two tables are the same in both queries. Perhaps there is strait what to convert my manual sql query to sqlalchemy orm syntax?

Edit:
My second version is working. I was just missing one paranthesis. I fixed the code above.
But why is my first try giving me a different result?

Answer (score 0):

I've not worked with SQLAlchemy yet, but perhaps you can solve your problem, if your arn't using a subquery. Take a look of the query below. Not tested an free translated from yours ;)

```
    SELECT a.* 
    FROM qsreport_test.JiraFehlerFreigabeReleaseTestData a 
    INNER JOIN qsreport_test.JiraFehlerFreigabeReleaseTestData b
     ON b.key = a.key
     AND b.testplanname=a.testplanname
     AND b.priority=a.priority
    GROUP BY a.testplanname, a.priority
    HAVING a.dtime = max(b.dtime)
```

Comment: Thanks for the advise. You remebered me to take thake a look at the definition of the different types of joins. I was always using an implicit inner join but using it explicitly is a good idea. While trying to setup this query I found out that i was missing one paranthesis in my secsond try (see my original post). It is now working.