# SQLAlchemy not building JOIN on select correctly

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to translate the following query into a SQLAlchemy ORM query:

```sql
SELECT applications.*, 
       appversions.version 
FROM   applications 
       JOIN appversions 
         ON appversions.id = (SELECT id 
                              FROM   appversions 
                              WHERE  appversions.app_id = applications.id 
                              ORDER  BY sort_ver DESC 
                              LIMIT  1)
```

The model for the tables are as follows:

```
Base = declarative_base()

class Application(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'applications'

    id       = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    group    = Column(Unicode(128))
    artifact = Column(Unicode(128))

    versions = relationship("AppVersion", backref = "application")

class AppVersion(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'versions'

    id        = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    app_id    = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('applications.id'))
    version   = Column(Unicode(64))
    sort_ver  = Column(Unicode(64))
```

And the query I've so far come up with is:

```
subquery = select([AppVersion.id]). \
                where(AppVersion.app_id == Application.id). \
                order_by(AppVersion.sort_ver). \
                limit(1). \
                alias()


query = session.query(Application). \
                join(AppVersion, AppVersion.id == subquery.c.id) \
                .all()
```

However, this is producing the following SQL statement and error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such column: anon_1.id
[SQL: SELECT applications.id AS applications_id, applications."group" AS applications_group, applications.artifact AS applications_artifact
FROM applications JOIN versions ON versions.id = anon_1.id]
```

I have tried various different methods to produce the subquery and attempting to 'tack on' the sub-SELECT command, but without any positive impact.

Is there a way to coerce the SQLAlchemy query builder to correctly append the sub-SELECT?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/6325582/2681632. Basically compare against the whole subquery, not a column of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With thanks to @Ilja Everilä for the nudge in the right direction, the code to generate the correct query is:

```
subquery = select([AppVersion.id]). \
                where(AppVersion.app_id == Application.id). \
                order_by(AppVersion.sort_ver). \
                limit(1). \
                correlate(Application)

query = session.query(Application). \
                join(AppVersion, AppVersion.id == subquery) \
                .all()
```

The main change is to use the *correlate()* method, which alters how SQLAlchemy constructs the subquery.

To explain why this works requires some understanding of how SQL subqueries are categorised and handled. The best explanation I have found is from  https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sql-correlated-subqueries/:

> With a normal nested subquery, the inner SELECT query runs first and executes once, returning values to be used by the main query. A correlated subquery, however, executes once for each candidate row considered by the outer query. In other words, the inner query is driven by the outer query.